# Failing to get multiple values using join

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have below scenario:

```
    create table t1 (id int, title varchar(20), description varchar(20));
    create table t2 (id int, info1 varchar(20), info2 varchar(20));
    create table t3 (id1 int auto_increment, info varchar(20), id int, primary key(id1));
    create table t4 (num int, name varchar(20), some varchar(20), lid int, sid int);
    create table t5 (sid int, sname varchar(20), addr varchar(50));
    create table t6 (url varchar(30), id int);

    insert into t1 values (1, "title1", "desc1");
    insert into t2 values (1, "test info1", "test info2");
    insert into t3 (id1, info, id) values (1, "info 1", 1), (2, "info 2", 1), (3, "info 3", 1);
    insert into t4 values (2121, 'name1', 'test1', '11', 1), (2323, 'name2', 'test2', '12', 2), (2232, 'name3', 'test3', '13', 3);
    insert into t5 values (1, 'sname1', 'addr1'), (2, 'sname2', 'addr2'), (3, 'sname3', 'addr3');
    insert into t6 values ('url1', 1), ('url2', 1), ('url3', 1);

    mysql> select * from t1;
    +------+--------+-------------+
    | id   | title  | description |
    +------+--------+-------------+
    |    1 | title1 | desc1       |
    +------+--------+-------------+

    mysql> select * from t2;
    +------+------------+------------+
    | id   | info1      | info2      |
    +------+------------+------------+
    |    1 | test info1 | test info2 |
    +------+------------+------------+

    mysql> select * from t3;
    +-----+--------+------+
    | id1 | info   | id   |
    +-----+--------+------+
    |   1 | info 1 |    1 |
    |   2 | info 2 |    1 |
    |   3 | info 3 |    1 |
    +-----+--------+------+

    mysql> select * from t4;
    +------+-------+-------+------+------+
    | num  | name  | some  | lid  | sid  |
    +------+-------+-------+------+------+
    | 2121 | name1 | test1 |   11 |    1 |
    | 2323 | name2 | test2 |   12 |    2 |
    | 2232 | name3 | test3 |   13 |    3 |
    +------+-------+-------+------+------+

    mysql> select * from t5;
    +------+--------+-------+
    | sid  | sname  | addr  |
    +------+--------+-------+
    |    1 | sname1 | addr1 |
    |    2 | sname2 | addr2 |
    |    3 | sname3 | addr3 |
    +------+--------+-------+

    mysql> select * from t6;
    +------+------+
    | url  | id   |
    +------+------+
    | url1 |    1 |
    | url2 |    1 |
    | url3 |    1 |
    +------+------+
```

And I am running below query to get values from the above tables:

```
    select
    t1.id,
    t1.title,
    t1.description,
    t2.id,
    t2.info1,
    t2.info2,
    t3.id1,
    t3.info,
    t4.num,
    t4.name,
    t4.some,
    t4.lid,
    t4.sid,
    t5.sname,
    t5.addr,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t6.url) SEPARATOR ',') as url
    from t1
    join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    join t3 on t3.id = t1.id
    join t4 on t4.sid = t3.id1
    join t5 on t5.sid = t3.id1
    join t6 on t6.id = t1.id
    group by t1.id
```

And I am getting below result:

```
+------+--------+-------------+------+------------+------------+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+-------+----------------+
| id   | title  | description | id   | info1      | info2      | id1 | info   | num  | name  | some  | lid  | sid  | sname  | addr  | url            |
+------+--------+-------------+------+------------+------------+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+-------+----------------+
|    1 | title1 | desc1       |    1 | test info1 | test info2 |   1 | info 1 | 2121 | name1 | test1 |   11 |    1 | sname1 | addr1 | url1,url2,url3 |
+------+--------+-------------+------+------------+------------+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+-------+----------------+
```

But instead of this I am expecting below result:

```
+------+--------+-------------+------+------------+------------+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+-------+----------------+
| id   | title  | description | id   | info1      | info2      | id1 | info   | num  | name  | some  | lid  | sid  | sname  | addr  | url            |
+------+--------+-------------+------+------------+------------+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+-------+----------------+
|    1 | title1 | desc1       |    1 | test info1 | test info2 |   1 | info 1 | 2121 | name1 | test1 |   11 |    1 | sname1 | addr1 | url1,url2,url3 |
|    1 | title1 | desc1       |    1 | test info1 | test info2 |   2 | info 2 | 2323 | name2 | test2 |   12 |    2 | sname2 | addr2 | url1,url2,url3 |
|    1 | title1 | desc1       |    1 | test info1 | test info2 |   3 | info 3 | 2232 | name3 | test3 |   13 |    3 | sname3 | addr3 | url1,url2,url3 |
+------+--------+-------------+------+------------+------------+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+-------+----------------+
```

Please help me. How can I get the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
group by t1.id
```

to

```
group by t1.id, t3.id1
              ^^^^^^^^
```

Output:

```
| ID |  TITLE | DESCRIPTION |      INFO1 |      INFO2 | ID1 |   INFO |  NUM |  NAME |  SOME | LID | SID |  SNAME |  ADDR |            URL |
|----|--------|-------------|------------|------------|-----|--------|------|-------|-------|-----|-----|--------|-------|----------------|
|  1 | title1 |       desc1 | test info1 | test info2 |   1 | info 1 | 2121 | name1 | test1 |  11 |   1 | sname1 | addr1 | url3,url2,url1 |
|  1 | title1 |       desc1 | test info1 | test info2 |   2 | info 2 | 2323 | name2 | test2 |  12 |   2 | sname2 | addr2 | url3,url2,url1 |
|  1 | title1 |       desc1 | test info1 | test info2 |   3 | info 3 | 2232 | name3 | test3 |  13 |   3 | sname3 | addr3 | url3,url2,url1 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7c78/2)** demo